# Getting a 422 Authorization error with Uber API

Tags: authorization, uber-api

I am testing my app for the first time, just trying to get basic info via the API but am getting an error: 422 Unprocessable Entity, "validation_failed".

What am I missing here?  I have tried it with both sandbox-api.uber.com and with api.uber.com.

getting back:

> code: "validation_failed" fields: {start_longitude:Required,
>   start_latitude:Required} start_latitude: "Required" start_longitude:
>   "Required" message: "Invalid request"

```
  var uberServerToken = "XXXXXXXXcEE0cHbwhKiF_sl_ZUYvEHHO_f6U6dr" ;
  $http({
    url: "https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time" ,
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Token " + uberServerToken
    },
    data: {
        start_latitude: setLat,
        start_longitude: setLon
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Ok, so I went back to developer.uber.com and verified the settings on my registered app.

Two things I had to add into my app profile:  1) my app is an android app, I added "http://localhost" as my redirect url - is this correct?  And "http://localhost/policy.html" as my Privacy Policy URL - both were required by the app uber profile/registration process.

2)  After entering the above info into my app profile, I am now getting a "503 Service Unavailable" error in my debug console for my app.

I am stuck trying to figure out how to connect to retrieve Uber products, times, prices for 4 days now

Comment: Well, look like #2 isn't an issue, seems the server http://api.uber.com/ was just slow or temporarily not responding.  HOWEVER, I am back to getting the "422 Unproccessable Entitty: validation_failed"

What in the world am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an access token for the request.  Grab the access code from the user, exchange that for an access_token, and provide the access_token with each request to Uber's API.

Link:  https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.